# android: return to Gallery after images are uploaded (any function substituting "back" button activity?)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back

My app is a simple uploader built for uploading image to web services.

User goes to the Gallery and uploads the images by pressing "Share" -> my app.
After uploaded, user gets a blank page and have to press "back" button to leave my app after the images are uploaded.

But I don't want user to press back button every time after upload the images.

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

Adding `finish();` after the upload activity will work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply type onBackPressed() when uploading is finished.